# Jmeter jmx file verification

Tags: security, jmeter

In my application user uploads his jmeter test plan (*.jmx file) and I need to execute it on my server. I want to verify that the jmx file does not contain any code that can harm my server. Are there any plugins, tools that can help me?

Comment: what do you mean by harm? how you define it? please post a specific problem that you are facing. It is a vague question

Comment: Inside a jmx file user can run shell commands like rm, mkdir, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter is **very** flexible and there is no way to stop the user from doing the harm as for example:

- It is possible do delete any file or folder using [Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) or [JavaScript](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)
- It is possible to read any file and send it over to anyone via [email](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)
- It is possible to fork too many processes or kick off too much threads and put your server on its knees by overloading it

So there is no any guaranteed way to verify a JMeter test, the best thing you can do is running it in isolated mode like:

1. Create a user with a very limited permissions set before executing the test and execute the test as this user
2. Use container mechanism like:

   - [Windows Containers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/about_overview)
   - [Linux Containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)
   - [FreeBSD Jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I was considering both options (user with limited access and containers). Just wanted to make sure I am not missing some known tool which is already doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through solutions like chroot, FreeBSD Jails and dockers, we choosed [Dockers](https://www.docker.com/). The advantages we found were:

- very easy setup and [cool documentation](https://docs.docker.com/)
- the docker starts in less than a second and there are lots of actions you can do with container - copy file into container, mount directory, run process inside container, etc.

I've created one container with jmeter in it. Every time I want to run some jmeter file I start the container, copy the jmx file into the container and run jmeter inside the container. Note that I call jmeter.sh outside of container and get the jmeter output into console again outside of container. When jmeter process is over, I stop the container.
Some commands I have used:

```
docker create --name container_name -it my_image_with_jmeter //create container from an image. my_image_with_jmeter is the name of the image I've created
docker start container_name
docker cp /path/to/main/server/file container_name:/path/to/container/ //copy file from main server to container
docker exec -it container_name /usr/local/jmeter/jmeter.sh // run jmeter inside container
docker stop container_name
```